# Lubridate a vector of intervals

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to deal with a set of lubridate intervals and to determine if a date is within any member of that set.
My intervals are non-overlapping, but a general answer would be best.)

I do not know how many intervals are in that set of intervals before I start the data analysis:

---

```
library(lubridate)

#Create 4 dates; 2 pairs

start1 <-ymd("2015-01-01")
stop1 <-ymd("2015-01-08")

start2 <-ymd("2015-02-01")
stop2 <-ymd("2015-02-08")

#Make 2 non-overlapping intervals

interval1 <-start1%--%stop1 

interval2 <-start2%--%stop2 

#two more dates, each within an interval

day1 <-ymd("2015-01-04")

day2 <-ymd("2015-02-04")

#now test the new dates against the intervals.

day1 %within%interval1 #TRUE

day2 %within%interval1 #FALSE

day2 %within%interval2 #TRUE
```

And I can do:

```
day2 %within%c(interval1, interval2) #(FALSE, TRUE)
```

which I am sure I can coerce into a TRUE if I think about it.

But how can I ask?:

```
#Don't Run:

INTERVALS <-c(interval1, interval2, ... intervalN)

day2 %within% INTERVALS
```

e.g. Did X happen when Y was working, where "when Y was working" is a vector of intervals.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize everything, and then use `lapply` to use `%within%` for each day you want to check:

```r
library(lubridate)

start <-ymd("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01")
stop <-ymd("2015-01-08", "2015-02-08")

days <-ymd("2015-01-04", "2015-02-04")

lapply(days, `%within%`, start %--% stop)
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

which is a list for each element of `days` with whether it is in each interval. To check whether each element of `days` is within any of the intervals, write an anonymous function for `*apply`:

```r
sapply(days, function(x){any(x %within% interval(start, stop))})
## [1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

With [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) and `iv_between()` to determine if a particular date fell between *any* of the intervals:

```r
library(ivs)
library(lubridate)

start1 <- ymd("2015-01-01")
stop1 <- ymd("2015-01-08")
start2 <- ymd("2015-02-01")
stop2 <- ymd("2015-02-08")

intervals <- iv_pairs(c(start1, stop1), c(start2, stop2))
intervals
#> <iv<date>[2]>
#> [1] [2015-01-01, 2015-01-08) [2015-02-01, 2015-02-08)

x <- ymd(c("2015-01-04", "2015-02-04"))
x
#> [1] "2015-01-04" "2015-02-04"

# Does `x[i]` fall between any intervals in `intervals`?
iv_between(x, intervals)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE

# If you want to know which intervals it fell between
iv_align(x, intervals, locations = iv_locate_between(x, intervals))
#>      needles                 haystack
#> 1 2015-01-04 [2015-01-01, 2015-01-08)
#> 2 2015-02-04 [2015-02-01, 2015-02-08)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chop()` from my santoku package:

```r
library(santoku)
chop(c(day1, day2), c(start1, stop1, start2, stop2))
##  [1] [2015-01-01, 2015-01-08) [2015-02-01, 2015-02-08)
## Levels: [2015-01-01, 2015-01-08) [2015-02-01, 2015-02-08)
```

Note that this will also capture anything between stop1 and start2. You could then select the intervals you care about. Or you could alter the labels:

```r
chop(c(day1, day2), c(start1, stop1, start2, stop2), 
       labels = c("Interval1", "Out2", "Interval2"))
## [1] Interval1 Interval2
## Levels: Interval1 Interval2
```